# Very lengthy stored procedure status

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which takes about 5-8 mins to execute.
The user just sees a message "Please wait while report is being generated"
It is very likely that people may think that it has stopped working ... or something went wrong.. etc..

Is there any way a stored procedure can keep returning status while executing..?

for example :

```
{logical block 1}
logical block 1 completed!
{logical block 2}
logical block 2 completed!
{logical block 3}
logical block 3 completed!
```

If yes, Please also tell me me how do I catch those status in c#.

Thanks guys.

Comment: do you have appropriate indexes?

Comment: Yes. The stored procedure is not the best. But this is what it going to be for the first release of website.

Comment: I don't want to increase the performance of SP right now.. just need to catch the status of stored procedure.

Comment: "Treat the cause, not the symptoms"

Comment: you can use Raiserror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting! Have you looked at non-severe RAISERROR? Look at [this article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/10/01/SQL-Server-Notify-client-of-progress-in-a-long-running.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`InfoMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to receive `PRINT` and `RAISERROR` messages on the client.

If that doesn't work, I'm afraid you'd have to split your stored procedure up into multiple smaller procedures to get the status at each step.